# Generating JSON of a JS-Object with only some attributes in JSON

Tags: javascript, json

I'm generating JSON from a javascript object. But I do not need all attributes from the object in the JSON. Is there a way (or a library) to do this? Till now, I overrided the toJSON function and return a new Object with reduced attributes, but its a nasty workaround, isn't it?

Comment: That is a very nasty workaround, unfortunately I can't think of anything else to do in this instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`JSON.stringify` accepts a second parameter, a "replacer" function, that you may be able to use to exclude certain properties.

```
var exclude = { 'akey': true };

var obj = { 'akey': 2, 'anotherkey': 3 };

JSON.stringify(obj, function (key, value) {
    if(exclude[key]) return undefined;
    return value;
});

=> "{'anotherkey':3}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Funny I just wrote some code to do this (with objects) which you can then serialize the target.

```
// sorta like $.extend but limits to updating existing properties
// from a template. takes any number of objects to merge.
function mergeObjects(template) {
    var obj={};
    if (arguments) {
        for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
            newObj = arguments[i];
            for (var prop in template) {
                if (newObj.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
                    obj[prop] = newObj[prop];
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return obj;
}
```

The way to use this function is with a template object that has the properties you need, e.g.

```
var template = {
  firstname: '',
  lastname: ''
}

var someObject = {
  firstname: "bryce",
  lastname: "nesbitt",
  title: "ubergeek"
}

var filteredObject = mergeObjects(template,someObject);
```

-->

```
   filteredObject: {
      firstname: "bryce",
      lastname: "nesbitt",
    }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/AARMW/